# PhpStorm shows warning on :src directive in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, path, phpstorm

I have Vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <img :src="file" alt=""/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'card',
        data() {
            return {
                file : 'assets/images/playingCards/backSide.jpg'
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

But inspection in PhpStorm gives me warning in `:src` directive:

> This inspection checks unresolved file references in HTML.

I've tried removing `:` from `src` (so classic html) and write path with PhpStorm autocomplete (to be 100% sure validity path) and this value bind in `data()` to key `file`... but problem persist.

How to tell PhpStorm about vue and directive? (I don't want turn off check for file references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue: [WEB-42737](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42737). Please follow it to be notified on updates.